# Desenvolver PDF417 com Delphi

Tags: delphi, código-de-barras

Boa tarde.
Uso um antigo gerador de relatórios para Delphi XE7 (**pReport**). Possuo o código fonte do mesmo, e já fiz bastante alterações nele. Agora mais um desafio, preciso incluir um novo tipo de **Código de barras** no gerador. Seria o `PDF417`.
Alguém tem alguma noção de como fazer isso?

Pelo que vi no projeto do gerador de relatórios, ele usa o **Vgr_BarCode**, que seria uma biblioteca livre mas que não é mais mantida. Essa biblioteca foi feita por **Andreas Schmidt** porém na hora de gerar códigos de barras 2D, a biblioteca foi descontinuada. Alguém usa essa biblioteca? Se sim, já a evoluiu?
Espero ter sido específico na pergunta.

Comment: Sua pergunta está um bocado ampla. Você já sabe gerar o código? Sabe desenhar o código? Sabe calcular o padrão? Seria importante [edit] a pergunta e deixar clara a dúvida exata, com a dificuldade específica que está tendo (preferencialmente com o estado atual do respectivo código).

Comment: Um bom esboço do padrão é esse: http://www.morovia.com/manuals/PDF417-Font-ware-Writer-SDK-4/chapter.overview.php

Comment: Nesse caso, sugiro que encontre um componente especifico para geração de código de barras, e utilize-o dentro do seu componente.
O correto, seria você abandonar esse framework, e partir para um mais novo. Nunca faça alterações em um componente que não é seu, para isso crie uma classe base desse componente e faça as suas edições lá. Imagina se você tivesse que dar um update nesses caras hoje?

Comment: Então @VictorZanella tentei não mexer no componente, mas tenho mais de 1000 relatórios gerados nesse gerador, e muitos são específicos em cada cliente. Usar um novo gerador é quase impossível, pois eu teria de convetere cada relatório e em cada cliente (Já tentei fazer, mas sem muito sucesso).

Comment: @Bacco Na verdade a resposta é não para todos os seus questionamentos. Por isso a pergunta **um bocado ampla**. No gerador que uso, apenas são aceitos códigos de barras 1D.

Comment: No caso, sugiro então que você encontre uma outra lib que gere o código no formato desejado. Tendo isso em mãos, é só implementar essa funcionalidade dentro desse gerador atual. Basicamente, você vai injetar uma extensão no que já tem hoje, oque acha da ideia ? Se concordar podemos dar sequencia com códigos.

Comment: @VictorZanella Concordo plenamente, acho que essa é realmente a saída. Já encontrei a lib que você mencionou [PDF417Lib](https://github.com/cdfmr/pas417lib). Estou tentando implementa-la dentro do gerador, mas com dificuldades, é outro padrão... O gerador de relatórios que uso pode ser encontrado em [pReport](https://sourceforge.net/projects/preport/). Obrigado.

Comment: Vamos lá, que falta pouco para eu conseguir te dar uma resposta. Instalei essa lib, e ele funcionou perfeitamente. Qual está sendo a sua dificuldade em incluir esse cara dentro do seu gerador de relatórios ?

Comment: Vou tentar explicar a dificuldade, no gerador de relatórios  posso colocar objetos na página. Quando insiro um `BarCode`, seleciono o tipo (**EAN13, Code39** e etc), nessa lista consegui inserir o **PDF417**. Olhando o código fonte do gerador, descobri onde é gerado a imagem montada com o código de barras, e nesse ponto é que não estou conseguindo _injetar_ o código da lib que você baixou.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Levando em consideração que basta adicionar a funcionalidade de gerar o código de barras e formato PDF417 com a "PDF417Lib", segue toturial:

Não há necessidade de instalar o dpk que vem junto, a menos que você queira implementar algo em tempo de design.

Primeiro passo, é adicionar no Search path do projeto ( Ctrl+Shift+F11 ) os seguintes diretórios:

```
...\pas417lib-master\vcl
...\pas417lib-master\src
```

Agora segue o código das classes que implementadas:

**BarcodeGenerator - Interface**

```
unit BarcodeGenerator;

interface

uses
  Graphics;

type
  IBarcodeGenerator = interface
    ['{BDBF2DC5-29CB-413F-9920-579D4213B638}']

    function GetPdf417(AValue: String): TBitmap;    
  end;

implementation

end.
```

**BarcodeGeneratorImpl - Implementação**

```
unit BarcodeGeneratorImpl;

interface

uses
  Graphics, PDF417Barcode, BarcodeGenerator;

type
  TBarcodeGeneratorImpl = class(TInterfacedObject, IBarcodeGenerator)

  private
    MyCodeBar: TPDF417BarcodeVCL;

  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;   
    function GetPdf417(AValue: String): TBitmap;   
  end;

implementation

uses
  SysUtils;

{ THelperBarcodeGenerator }

constructor TBarcodeGeneratorImpl.Create;
begin
  MyCodeBar := TPDF417BarcodeVCL.Create(nil);
end;

destructor TBarcodeGeneratorImpl.Destroy;
begin
  FreeAndNil(MyCodeBar);
  inherited;
end;

function TBarcodeGeneratorImpl.GetPdf417(AValue: String): TBitmap;
begin
  MyCodeBar.Lines.Add(AValue);
  Result := MyCodeBar.Bitmap;
end;

end.
```

Agora neste exemplo, foi criado uma unit normal, com a parte visual, foram adicionado um TEdit, um TImage e um TButton.

**Exemplo de utilização**

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes,
   Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    Image1: TImage;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);    
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

uses
  BarcodeGenerator, BarcodeGeneratorImpl;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  FBarcodeGenerator: IBarcodeGenerator;
begin    
  FBarcodeGenerator     := TBarcodeGeneratorImpl.Create;
  Image1.Picture.Bitmap := FBarcodeGenerator.GetPdf417(Edit1.Text);   
end;

end.
```

Acredito que com as 2 units BarcodeGenerator e BarcodeGeneratorImpl, fica fácil você injetar essa função no seu framework.

Comment: Vlw Zanella... hoje não da mais tempo.. mas acredito que é a solução que eu precisava. Obrigado mesmo (de novo)!

Comment: se não der, comenta aqui, que a gente dá uma olhada.

Comment: Estou com dificuldades para injetar o código no gerador de relatório. Agora irei abusar de sua boa vontade, preciso de alguém para trocar ideias sobre o gerador de relatórios que comentei dias atrás (pReport). Se você puder baixa-lo e instala-lo, seria de muitíssima ajuda. Muito obrigado. @Victor Zanella

Comment: Primeiro vou precisar dos fontes desse componente, e depois das alterações que você customizou nela. Pode me passar esses dados?

Comment: Tudo o que você precisa está nesse [Link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsdeyPnDikoZgWaP5PTZVNSHEl70) Incluindo um tutorial básico de instalação dos componentes. Esses fontes já estão com as alterações que fiz. Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Cara, o dpk tenta criar arquivos dentro do disco P:/. Eu não tenho disco P:/ e mesmo criando, ele vai dar mais erros. Me diz qual a unit que você quer colocar a Geração do PDF417, que eu monto alguma coisa aqui.

Comment: Bem, em mode _Designer_ do relatório eu tenho a possibilidade de inserir um objeto `CodeBar`. Meu interesse é que nesse componente seja acrescentado na lista a opção **PDF417**. Esse código de barras seja colocado no layout, depois visualizado (_Preview_) e por fim impresso quando o usuário solicitar. Acredito que as `units` sejam as que referenciem _CodeBar_. Porém, estou tentando fazer de um outro modo, que seria inserir um `Image` e criar nele o código de barra, acho até que essa era sua ideia original. Caso eu consiga fazer, te informo. Obrigado.

Comment: ok, qualquer coisa avisa

Comment: Muito bom, usei para criar uma documentação. Alguém fez um código para leitura do PDF417 também?